# How can I create a forecast data

Tags: tableau-desktop, calculated-field

My version of Tableau is very limited as I cannot use external sources such as Excel, it only uses an internal database from where I can export the performance of my teams.

How can I create a forecast field in Tableau per teams if I have the full year targets values per team? Then I want to use this field for performance vs target calculations and visualisation.

I have created a calculated field called 'Forecast per Team' but when I try to convert it in numbers or measures it gives me zeros. What am I doing wrong?